# Windows Batch Goto

Tags: batch-file, hash

First time actually posting questions on this forum so don't be rough >:( .

I am trying to make  a little batch file that takes the MD5 hashes of few files in a folder and checks if they are the same with the one that i want but i get stuck ..

```
if "!md2temp!"=="d1 9e 93 c0 a2 94 59 10 66 44 af 17 ea c5 56 2c" goto verificat
if "!md2temp!"=="d2 19 c0 a8 af f2 c7 71 94 6d 73 55 49 16 bd 9a" goto verificat
if "!md2temp!"=="8d f4 d4 32 4e 57 55 f1 a0 56 7d b3 c5 be 4c 58" goto verificat
if "!md2temp!"=="f9 56 47 0c 7f 50 91 01 02 21 a0 5b 7e 2f 19 92" goto verificat
if "!md2temp!"=="64 00 e2 24 b8 b4 4e ce 59 a9 92 e6 d8 23 37 19" goto verificat
if "!md2temp!"=="1a c3 d6 12 38 9f a6 79 f5 ca 3c 6b ab 85 51 45" goto verificat
if "!md2temp!"=="18 95 76 df e5 5a f3 b7 0d b7 e3 e2 31 2c d0 fd" goto verificat
goto fals
```

Notice that i have the md5 hashes saved in md5ttt.tmp in this format :

```
d1 9e 93 c0 a2 94 59 10 66 44 af 17 ea c5 56 2c
d2 19 c0 a8 af f2 c7 71 94 6d 73 55 49 16 bd 9a
8d f4 d4 32 4e 57 55 f1 a0 56 7d b3 c5 be 4c 58
f9 56 47 0c 7f 50 91 01 02 21 a0 5b 7e 2f 19 92
64 00 e2 24 b8 b4 4e ce 59 a9 92 e6 d8 23 37 19
1a c3 d6 12 38 9f a6 79 f5 ca 3c 6b ab 85 51 45
18 95 76 df e5 5a f3 b7 0d b7 e3 e2 31 2c d0 fd
```

But this doesn't satisfy me because after the first check it goes to *:verificat* but what i want is : if all of them are verified it can go to :verified.

And if there appears a new one (the md5ttt.tmp will look just like this : )

```
d1 9e 93 c0 a2 94 59 10 66 44 af 17 ea c5 56 2c
d2 19 c0 a8 af f2 c7 71 94 6d 73 55 49 16 bd 9a
8d f4 d4 32 4e 57 55 f1 a0 56 7d b3 c5 be 4c 58
f9 56 47 0c 7f 50 91 01 02 21 a0 5b 7e 2f 19 92
64 00 e2 24 b8 b4 4e ce 59 a9 92 e6 d8 23 37 19
1a c3 d6 12 38 9f a6 79 f5 ca 3c 6b ab 85 51 45
18 95 76 df e5 5a f3 b7 0d b7 e3 e2 31 2c d0 fd
2a 3b 87 kd 93 op oz n2 c7 bb k6 78 91 d9 9f c5
4d n4 83 d9 a0 kp 93 21 2h g8 l0 c1 fd d1 7d c2
```

Notice that there are 2 new hashes .. 
And if it appears a new hash it should goto :fals 
Help please ? :D

Comment: instead of testing if they are equal, send it to notverificat if they are not equal and then after all the tests jump to verificat because they were all equal.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah uuuuh can't get you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this code is used in a loop. Count the lines read from the file `md5ttt.tmp`and count the successful md5 hash compares. After the loop compare the two counts and check on equality.

```
rem Code before the loop
set "LineCount=0"
set "HashCount=0"

rem Code inside the loop
set /A LineCount+=1
if "!md2temp!"=="d1 9e 93 c0 a2 94 59 10 66 44 af 17 ea c5 56 2c" set /A HashCount+=1
if "!md2temp!"=="d2 19 c0 a8 af f2 c7 71 94 6d 73 55 49 16 bd 9a" set /A HashCount+=1
if "!md2temp!"=="8d f4 d4 32 4e 57 55 f1 a0 56 7d b3 c5 be 4c 58" set /A HashCount+=1
if "!md2temp!"=="f9 56 47 0c 7f 50 91 01 02 21 a0 5b 7e 2f 19 92" set /A HashCount+=1
if "!md2temp!"=="64 00 e2 24 b8 b4 4e ce 59 a9 92 e6 d8 23 37 19" set /A HashCount+=1
if "!md2temp!"=="1a c3 d6 12 38 9f a6 79 f5 ca 3c 6b ab 85 51 45" set /A HashCount+=1
if "!md2temp!"=="18 95 76 df e5 5a f3 b7 0d b7 e3 e2 31 2c d0 fd" set /A HashCount+=1

rem Code after the loop
if !LineCount! == !HashCount! goto verificat
```

Comment: yeah so i deleted the temp files that my batch dumped and now your code works perfectly. thanks  a lot !